# A dictionary that returns number of word and each word's lenght Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, cpu-word

```
`slova=0

 a=input("Enter a sentence: ")
 str(a)

for letter in a:
    slova+=1
if letter==' ':
    slova-=1
elif letter=='.':
    slova-=1
elif letter==',':
    slova-=1
elif letter=='!':
    slova-=1
elif letter=='?':
    slova-=1

print(slova)
```

`So I want to make a programme that takes a sentence as the input from the user and than returns how many words that sentence has, how many characters, and most important the lenght of each word. I thought about using a dictonary that uses a word name as a key and the lenght as a value.This is a programe that returns number of only letters. I also have one that returns all characters and I thought about connecting them somehow with dictionry  to get number of letter for each word but I really don't know how. Example:

I am felling good.

words: 4

characters: 18

I: 1

am: 2

felling: 7

good: 4

Comment: Please try something and then we can help :)

Comment: What would the output be if your sentence was "words and characters"? Would the "words" key have a value of 3 or 5?

Comment: Add your current code, even if it's giving syntax error :)

Comment: @SpoonMeiser the output would be 5

Comment: `len("I am felling good.")` &`len("I am felling good.".split(' '))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sample = "i am feeling good"

output = {}
output["word"] = len(sample.split())
output["chars"] = len(list(sample))
for elem in sample.split():
    output[elem] = len(list(elem))
print(output)
```

output:

```
{'word': 4, 'chars': 17, 'i': 1, 'am': 2, 'feeling': 7, 'good': 4}
```